# Call a function without method invocation operator

Tags: python

I have a curses program that I want to invoke from Python shell by just typing `hh`.

So, I have tried this:

```
class hh:
    def __str__(self):
        curses.wrapper(main)
    def __repr__(self):
        curses.wrapper(main)
```

...and then in shell:

```
>>> from package.module import hh
>>> hh
<class 'package.module.hh'>
```

However, had no success as you can see.

How can I invoke my curses program from Python shell by just typing `hh`? That is, is it possible to call a function without the method invocation operator, i.e., with no parentheses? Or what else could I do that would have had the same effect?

Comment: You can call a `staticmethod` without instantiating the object first

Comment: `hh` is just a *class*, you don't even have an instance for the methods you *have* defined to be called on. If you want to implement the repr method on the *class*, you need to look into *metaclasses*. Not returning a string is a `TypeError`, though.

Comment: Those are some pretty strange (bordeing on abuse) overloads, but they also apply to instances of `hh`, not to the class.